# How to decide the p and q for GARCH model?

Tags: r, time-series, garch

My question is simple. When shall I stop when trying the value for p and q?

I have got the loglikelihood from ARCH(1) to ARCH(10). It's increasing. And then I tried GARCH(1,1), GARCH(2,1) etc. The loglikelihood is always increasing so I'm confused. Do I need to continue to apply for larger lags until the log likelihood start to decrease? What argument shall I make when I stop trying?

Comment: Are you using straight log likelihood or a penalized version like AIC / BIC?

Comment: I'm using straight log likelihood. Shall I include AIC as another critieria?

Comment: I'm not an expert in time series, but unless I'm strongly mistaken, moving from (eg) ARCH(1) to ARCH(2) amounts to adding another parameter / predictor to the model. So of course it would make the model *look* like it fits better (even if it doesn't really). You would need some sort of penalty to account for this fact.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help =]  You are right. I just checked and I decides to use AIC because AIC is like the likelihood plus the penalty of adding more parameters.

Comment: I agree with gung that you should use AIC/BIC instead of likelihood for this kind of problem. Also, you may look at residual diagnostics to see how good a job your model does in terms of capturing the conditional heteroskedasticity.

Answer (score 2):

As the commenters point out, increasing ARCH/GARCH orders amounts to including additional degrees of freedom, so the (log) likelihood is guaranteed to increase. If you simply follow this increase in (log) likelihood, you will overfit.

One possibility would be to balance the gain in (log) likelihood against model complexity by adding a penalty term. Information criteria like the AIC or BIC are helpful here.

Here is an alternative. ARCH and GARCH are fundamentally ways to forecast future *volatility*. They aim at producing good density forecasts, by modeling the conditional heteroskedasticity. So one way of choosing model orders would be to fit each model, then create density forecasts for a holdout sample and assess which model gives the best density forecast. Possible tools would be the Probability Integral Transform or (proper) [scoring-rules](/questions/tagged/scoring-rules).